# Computing a tweaked definition of entropy

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, information-theory

Let $E$ be a set of size $n$. I define a probability measure on the (unordered) pairs, $p_{ij} = p_{ji}$ with $\sum_i \sum_{j\leq i} p_{ij} = 1$.

I want to compute a tweaked definition of entropy. Given a sequence of unordered pairs $\{i, j\}$   generated from $p_{ij}$, imagine the following game with players A and B:

- A chooses either $i$ or $j$ and encodes it. We note $z(i,j) \in \{i, j\}$ her choice (we admit that the optimal choice is deterministic).
- B has to retrieve the element encoded by A

The goal is for B to retrieve all elements perfectly while minimizing the expected size of the messages between A and B. Note $q_i$ the probability for A to output $i$,

$$q_i = \sum_{j | z(ij) = i} p_{ij}$$

The average number of bits per message is given by

$$\min_q H(q) = \min_{z,q} -\sum_i \sum_{j\leq i} p_{ij} \log q_{z(ij)} \geq \min_q -\sum_i \sum_{j\leq i} p_{ij} \log \max(q_i, q_j)$$

since $q_{z(ij)} \in \{q_i, q_j\}$.

By optimality, it is an equality and $z$ is a total order that can be retrieved only from the values of $q$.

In other words, there is a permutation $\sigma$ such that  $q_{\sigma(1)} \leq q_{\sigma(2)} \leq \cdots \leq q_{\sigma(n)}$ and $q_{\sigma(i)} = \sum_{j\leq i} p_{\sigma(j)}$.

Now my problem is to find $\sigma$ in a computationally efficient manner.
From the above properties, $\sigma$ minimizes the entropy of $q$.

Assuming we swap two numbers $i$ and $j$, the difference of entropy will be:

$$q_i \log q_i + q_j \log q_j - (q_i - p_{ij}) \log(q_i - p_{ij}) - (q_j + p_{ij}) \log (q_j + p_{ij})$$

By convexity of $x \rightarrow x \log x + (A-x) \log(A-x)$, the sign of this expression is the same as the sign of $\max(q_i, q_j) - \max(q_i - p_{ij}, q_j + p_{ij})$.

Does this define a total order? If yes, there is a $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, unfortunately.

Taking

```
array([[0.0085856 , 0.12780165, 0.20430139],
       [0.18213903, 0.03664946, 0.01016184],
       [0.14090394, 0.09401242, 0.19544468]])
```

the optimum is 1.00 with the permutation (0,1,2).

(1,2,0) gives 1.09 and (1,0,2) gives 1.11 so swapping 0 and 2 does not improve the score.